# Search for string ignoring new lines

Tags: search, isearch

I am used to writing files where paragraphs are split into several lines, e.g. with `fill-column`. When I search for a string (`C-s`) such as `this is a long text`, the search results would not return the locations where the string appears with a line break between two of the words (like `this\nis a long text`).

Is there a command that would also return these results?

Answer (score 13):

Take a look at the variables `isearch-lax-whitespace`, `isearch-regexp-lax-whitespace`, and `search-whitespace-regexp`.

If the first two variables are set to something non-nil (e.g. `t`) any space character in your search string will match any sequence matched by the regular expression defined by the `search-whitespace-regexp` variable.

To match words across line breaks do this:

```lisp
;; Make Isearch work across spaces, tabs, and newlines.
(setq isearch-lax-whitespace t
      isearch-regexp-lax-whitespace t
      search-whitespace-regexp "[ \t\r\n]+")
```

A space character in your query will now match any space, tab, or linebreak any number of times.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not work for me. My Emacs version is 23.4.1. Apparently it does not have an "isearch-lax-whitespace" variable.

Comment: Yeah, these features were introduced in Emacs 24.3.  Any chance of upgrading to a more recent version?  Version 23.4.1 is already more than three years old.

Comment: Try `isearch-forward-word`, which is bound to `M-s w` in recent Emacs.

Comment: Emacs 23 didn't work for me, make sure you're using 24.